# Random connection problems with Amazon SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, apache-commons-email

Recently I started using Amazon SES. My first attempt was to use port 25, but I had a lot of connection problems. After some search I found that EC2 throttles port 25 traffic to avoid spam, so I changed to port 587, but from about 1000 daily emails, about five times I get SMTP connection exceptions in my application.

I'm considering it random because the few emails that fail are in different parts of the application and I didn't found any pattern between them.

My sending quota is 10000 and there are less than 50 recipients in the emails. Is it normal that sometimes sending fails?

Thanks in advance.

**I'm using apache commons email 1.3.2 with the following settings:**

```
setCharset("UTF-8");
setHostName("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
setFrom("..."); // email from a verified domain
setAuthentication("...", "..."); // amazon smtp credentials
setSmtpPort(587);
setStartTLSEnabled(true);
setStartTLSRequired(true);
```

**Exceptions:**

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at br.com.spdata.email.HtmlEmail.send(HtmlEmail.java:136)
    at br.com.spdata.persistence.mysql.service.chat.AtendimentoService.doEnviarCopiaPorEmail(AtendimentoService.java:1112)
    at br.com.spdata.persistence.mysql.service.chat.AtendimentoService.access$000(AtendimentoService.java:62)
    at br.com.spdata.persistence.mysql.service.chat.AtendimentoService$1.run(AtendimentoService.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [EOF]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:823)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:756)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:673)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
```

|

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
    at br.com.spdata.jsf.util.JsfUtil.handleException(JsfUtil.java:236)
    at br.com.spdata.tecnico.page.agenda.AutorizacaoVisitaController.persist(AutorizacaoVisitaController.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2446.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at br.com.spdata.tecnico.filter.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at br.com.spdata.email.HtmlEmail.send(HtmlEmail.java:136)
    at br.com.spdata.persistence.mysql.service.ScAgendaService.sendEmailConfirmacaoAgendamento(ScAgendaService.java:975)
    at br.com.spdata.tecnico.page.agenda.AutorizacaoVisitaController.persist(AutorizacaoVisitaController.java:168)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2163)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2150)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2074)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2111)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.data(SMTPTransport.java:1887)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1490)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:70)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:114)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2161)
    ... 68 more
```

|

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at br.com.spdata.email.HtmlEmail.send(HtmlEmail.java:136)
    at br.com.spdata.persistence.mysql.service.chat.AtendimentoService.notificarChatSemAtendente(AtendimentoService.java:1541)
    at br.com.spdata.persistence.model.chat.AbstractAtendimentoBean.handleChatSemAtendente(AbstractAtendimentoBean.java:310)
    at br.com.spdata.persistence.model.chat.AbstractAtendimentoBean.entrar(AbstractAtendimentoBean.java:295)
    at br.com.spdata.cliente.page.atendimento.AtendimentoBean.entrar(AtendimentoBean.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1416.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at br.com.spdata.cliente.filter.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at br.com.spdata.cliente.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:89)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2188)
    ... 58 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using SMTPS with port 465.

Commons Email doesn't seem to handle SSL well, since isSSL always appears as false in debug mode. So I overrided the send method from HtmlEmail:

```
@Override
public String send() throws EmailException
{
    buildMimeMessage();

    // Implementação padrão de send() não conecta corretamente via SSL
    Transport transport = null;
    try
    {
        message.saveChanges();

        transport = getMailSession().getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 465, <<amazon SMTP username>>, <<amazon SMTP pasword>>);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        return message.getMessageID();
    }
    catch(MessagingException e)
    {
        throw new EmailException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(transport != null)
        {
            try
            {
                transport.close();
            }
            catch(MessagingException e)
            {
                throw new EmailException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are not exceeding the send limit and the send rate - sounds like you are within the sending quota, but perhaps you are exceeding the allowed send rate:

- **Sending Quota**—The maximum number of emails that you can send in a
  24-hour period. The sending quota reflects a rolling time period.
  Every time you try to send an email, Amazon SES checks how many
  emails you sent in the previous 24 hours.
- **Maximum Send Rate**—The maximum number of emails that you can send per
  second. You can exceed this limit for short bursts, but not for a
  sustained period of time.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-limits.html

Also, it seems like you are saying that sometimes you have 50 +/- recipients listed on a single email. AWS SES recommends that you limit your emails to one recipient.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my question so many times that I forgot to put that my application sends about 2000 emails daily, so the quota is fine. 

I agree about the single recipient by email, but I had to optimize a process that sends up to 1500 emails in sequence. According to the documentation the limit of recipients is 50, so sending it in batches of 50 made the process much faster.

I solved these connection problems by using smtps, I'll write an answer to describe it better.